# Unity drag object is not identifying after dragging a circle object

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, unity-game-engine

After dragging circle gameobject no other gameobject get score. but when I dragged this circle gameobject at the last every gameobject gets scored. I am not getting where is the problem.but circle get scored  after every gameobject
I am thinking there is some extra bracket which is blocking in get scored. Circle is getting scored even after any object but some objects can not get scored after someobjects. Every game object get scored when I dropped it first but sometime some gameobject did not get scored after dropping after circle or any other game bject
after circle ----- no object get scored

triangle-----circle and square

square----rectangle and circle

rectangle----circle

star----triangle, rectangle, circle

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class sh_score : MonoBehaviour {

    static int score = 0;
    public Text scoreText;

    public GameObject ans_circle;
    public GameObject tag_circle;
    public GameObject tag_rectangle;
    public GameObject ans_rectangle;
    public GameObject ans_triangle;
    public GameObject tag_triangle;
    public GameObject ans_square;
    public GameObject tag_square;
    public GameObject ans_star;
    public GameObject tag_star;
    bool circle_score = true,
         triangle_score = true,
         square_score = true,
         star_score = true,
         rectangle_score = true;





    void Start()
    {
        score = score;

        if ((ans_circle == null || tag_circle == null) || (ans_square == null || tag_square == null) || (ans_rectangle == null || tag_rectangle == null) || (ans_square == null || tag_square == null) || (ans_triangle == null || tag_triangle == null) || (ans_star == null || tag_star == null))
        {
            ans_circle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_circle");
            if (ans_circle != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("ans circle Find");
            }

            tag_circle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("circle");
            if (tag_circle != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("circle");
            }



            ans_rectangle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_rectangle");
            if (ans_rectangle != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("ans Find");
            }

            tag_rectangle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("rectangle");
            if (tag_circle != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("rectangle");
            }




            ans_triangle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_triangle");
            if (ans_triangle != null)
            { Debug.Log("ans Find"); }

            tag_triangle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("triangle");
            if (tag_triangle != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("triangle");
            }


            ans_star = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_star");
            if (ans_star != null)
            { Debug.Log("ans Find"); }

            tag_star = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("star");
            if (tag_star != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("star");
            }


            ans_square = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_square");
            if (ans_square != null)
            { Debug.Log("ans Find"); }

            tag_square = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("square");
            if (tag_square != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("square");
            }
        }

    }





    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();

        checkTagPlace();


    }



    public void IncrementScore()
    {

        score = score + 9;
        score++;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }

    public void checkTagPlace()
    {
        Debug.Log("check function run");

        if (ans_circle.transform.position.x == tag_circle.transform.position.x)
        {
            Debug.Log("found position");
            if (circle_score == true)
            {
                IncrementScore();
                circle_score = false;
            }



        }
        else if (ans_rectangle.transform.position.x == tag_rectangle.transform.position.x)
        {
            if (rectangle_score == true)
            {
                IncrementScore();
                 rectangle_score = false;
            }
        }
        else if ((ans_square.transform.position.x == tag_square.transform.position.x))
        {
            if (square_score == true)
            {
                IncrementScore();
                square_score = false;
            }
        }
        else if (ans_triangle.transform.position.x == tag_triangle.transform.position.x)
        {
            if (triangle_score == true)
            {
                IncrementScore();
                triangle_score = false;
            }
        }

        else if (ans_star.transform.position.x == tag_star.transform.position.x)
        {
            if (star_score == true)
            {
                IncrementScore();
                 star_score = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: circle can get scorred after every game object but no other gameobject can get scored after placing circle and other are mentoned above